# Showing what is displayed in ListBox in Alphabetical Order

Tags: c#, winforms

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gurgQ.jpg
Grabs users contacts, and randomly displays them, how can I make it show alphabetically though, so its easier to find a certain one.

Heres some code, dont know if any would need it.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I entered a message box so it doesn't crash instantly.
        MessageBox.Show("Please allow SkypeBot.vshost.exe to access skype if you haven't yet. (Look at your Skype application)");
        Skype skype = new Skype();
        skype.Attach();
        getContacts(skype);
    }

    List<string> Contacts = new List<string>();

    public void getContacts(Skype skype)
    {
        //This goes through all the contacts in the contacts list
        for (int i = 0; i < skype.HardwiredGroups.Count; i++)
        {
            //This checks if the user is a friend or not
            if (skype.HardwiredGroups[i + 1].Type == TGroupType.grpAllFriends)
            {
                //If they are, then do this loop
                for (int j = skype.HardwiredGroups[i + 1].Users.Count; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    //This adds the contact to the Contacts list we declared before.
                    Contacts.Add(skype.HardwiredGroups[i + 1].Users[j].Handle);
                }
            }
        }
        //This makes the listBox show the contents of the Contact list.
        listBox1.DataSource = Contacts;
    }
        //aot stands for amount of times.
    public void sendMessage(string message, string user, int aot, Skype skype)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < aot; i++)
        {
            skype.SendMessage(user, message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can simply use `Sorted` property of `ListBox`. Also you can use `listBox1.DataSource= Contacts.OrderBy(x => x).ToList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort items alphabetically you can simply set [`Sorted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `ListBox` to true.

Also using linq, you can use [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby(v=vs.100).aspx) method to sort ascending or [`OrderByDescending`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending(v=vs.100).aspx) method to to sort descending:

```
listBox1.DataSource= Contacts.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it, is sorting the contacts before binding it:

`listBox1.DataSource = Contacts.OrderBy( x => x ).ToList();`