# Sort listBox by date string c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listbox

I'm attempting to sort listBox Items by date, but not sure how to do this. I've managed to create a string that contains the date using Regex, but I'm not sure how to use this string to sort the listBox. Any advice would be appreciated.. Please see my code below.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("../Debug/");
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string dueDate = File.ReadAllText(file.Name);

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}");
    Match mat = regex.Match(dueDate);

    string duedate = mat.ToString();//string containing date
    listBox1.Items.Add(file);
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to read the date from? Filename or file-content?

Comment: [Showing what is displayed in ListBox in Alphabetical Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963484/showing-what-is-displayed-in-listbox-in-alphabetical-order)

Comment: @JonnyAppleseed Take care that you are using `ReadAllText` on `file.Name` which cant work as the `file.Name` will return only its name, not the path. So either user `ReadAllText(file)` or if you want the name itself `string dueDate = file.Name`.

Comment: If you go for using a class for your items (as I have suggested to your other question) you can add a date property and fill it when you create the instances. This could be used for sorting. As it stands you seem to be jumping issues without really knowing where you are and where you want to go..  Hint: you most likely want to switch to a ListView.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Alphabetical order won't work for dates

Comment: @Tharwen Did you read the linked question and answers? Just the title of question is alphabetical order, but you can also use linq methods as is offered in both answers. Also when using `d{2}` for day and month, as is used by the OP` alphabetical order will work properly.

Comment: @C4ud3x, the date is currently being read from the contents of the .txt file

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach it:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"../Debug/");
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");
Dictionary<FileInfo, DateTime> filesWithDueDate = new Dictionary<FileInfo, DateTime>();

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string dueDate = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);

    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}");
    Match mat = regex.Match(dueDate);

    DateTime duedate = Convert.ToDateTime(mat.ToString());

    filesWithDueDate.Add(file, duedate);
}

var sortedFiles = filesWithDueDate.OrderBy(a => a.Value).Select(b => b.Key.Name).ToArray();

listBox1.Items.AddRange(sortedFiles);
```

Comment: Thanks @jarednaszler.   Nearly works, unfortunately it has populated the listBox with multiple instances of each item.....

Comment: @JonnyAppleseed - It will list one item per file in that folder.  Do you only need unique due dates or something else?

Comment: receiving " String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." error for  " DateTime duedate = Convert.ToDateTime(mat.ToString());".. Any ideas... I did get it working flawlessly with your help...

Comment: Every one of your dates need to be 00/00/0000.  If you have any single digit day (12/3/2016), month (4/15/2016) dates, 2-digit years (04/15/16) or any combination of the above your RegEx will not match.  You can check if `mat.Success == true` property after you call the `regex.Match()`.  If it doesn't match though you will not see that file listed in the list box.

Comment: @JonnyAppleseed - did you get this working?  If not let's close this question up and accept the answer.  Otherwise let me know what is still not working and we can figure it out.